# Combining immutable lists of strings with each other

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, immutable.js

## The Problem

Create a javascript method which combines each string of two immutable lists with each other:

```
const a1 = new List(['a', 'b', 'c']);
const a2 = new List(['x', 'y', 'z']);

const combinedArray = combineArrays(a1,a2);
=> combinedArray: ['a-x', 'a-y', 'a-z', 'b-x', 'b-y', 'b-z', 'c-x', 'c-y', 'c-z']
```

## My Solution

```
import { List } from 'immutable';

const combineArray = (arrayA = new List([]), arrayB = new List([])) => {
  if (arrayA.count() === 0) {
  return arrayB;
}

if (arrayB.count() === 0) {
  return arrayA;
}

let combinations = new List([]);

combinations = arrayA.reduce((accum, value) => {
  if (value) {
    return accum.push(arrayB.reduce((accum2, value2) => {
      if (value2) {
        return accum2.push(`${value}-${value2}`);
      }
      return value;
    }, new List([])));
  }

  return accum;
}, new List([]));

  return combinations.flatten(true);
};

export default combineArray;
```

## Updated Solution

based on @bergis response I updated the implementation

```
import { List } from 'immutable';

const combineArray = (arrayA = new List([]), arrayB = new List([])) => {
  if (arrayA.isEmpty()) { return arrayB; }
  if (arrayB.isEmpty()) { return arrayA; }

  return arrayA.flatMap(valueA => (
    arrayB.map(valueB => (
      `${valueA}-${valueB}`
    ))
  ));
};

export default combineArray;
```

## My Question

- Would you have concerns regarding performance? (We are talking about a maximum of 10 items per list)
- How would you improve the implementation?

Comment: What's the point of checking `if (value)`? Also you have a mistake in the inner callback, needs to be `return accum2` not `return value`.

Comment: Don't use `reduce`. Use `map`, that's what it was made for. Not sure whether there even might be a `flatMap`.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for pointing this error out.

Comment: @Keith. I feel the same. That's why I am here asking for some reverences which could help me improving the implementation.

Comment: @schnika Now that looks good! I'd guess there's even some `isEmpty()` method or so, so that you don't need to do `count() == 0`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction and your guidance. I updated the snippet accordingly. Tests are green and code looks better now :)